# Asterisk: execute shell command on server when call is accepted on SIP extension

Tags: asterisk, sip

I'm trying to configure asterisk to execute shell command for incoming calls - but only when the call is accepted. I've managed to setup extensions.conf so that command is executed when new call comes in.

```
exten => 999999999,1,NoOp("----------mygroup---------------")
exten => 999999999,2,System(echo "1:${EXTEN} -  ${DATETIME} - ${CALLERID} - ${CHANNEL}" >> /var/log/asterisk/calls)
exten => 999999999,3,Dial(SIP/7001,20)
```

Is it possible to change it so that command is executed when operator connected to a SIP extension picks up the call. I need to know ID of the active operator and caller's number to execute the command.

Comment: Asterisk has built-in facilities for reading and writing files. An alternative to using `System` would be to use the `FILE()` function. For example, line 2 could be rewritten as `Set(FILE(/var/log/asterisk/calls,,,a)=1:${EXTEN} - ${DATETIME} - ${CALLERID} - ${CHANNEL})`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the "M" option for the Dial command.  Have the macro you trigger do whatever look-up you need to determine the the Operator info, and then run the System command from within the macro.

**Further Reading:**

- https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Application_Dial